# Htaccess redirect from subdirectory in one domain to another domain subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect, http-redirect

I am trying to create a permanent htaccess redirect (301) from all files in one directory in one domain, to another domain sub-directory as follows:

Redirect all files in the following directory:

from: **www.xxx.com**/apps/forms/reg.html

to: **www.yyy.com**/apps/forms/reg.html

if someone entered the **first url** it should redirect to the **second url**

Please help on this to fix my redirection issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1.extension$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.extension$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It should be either `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.extension/$1 [L,R=301]` or `RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.extension%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`. The first argument does not include a leading slash in per-directory context.